# Insert element (TinyXml)

Tags: c++, tinyxml

I want to add the element in the xml file. Can anyone help me to do that?

Following is my code tryout.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <category1>
        <category2 name="1">1.79639 0.430521</category2 >
        <category2 name="2">2.06832 0.652695</category2 >
        <category2 name="3">1.23123 0.111212</category2 >    <-- new
    </category1>
```

code:

```
 if (doc.LoadFile()) {
                TiXmlHandle docHandle(&doc);
                TiXmlElement* fileLog = docHandle.FirstChild("category1").ToElement();
                if (fileLog) {
                    TiXmlElement newCategory2("category2");
                    newCategory2.SetAttribute("name", "5");
                    fileLog->InsertEndChild(newCategory2);
                }
            }
```

Hope to get help from anyone.

Comment: This problem decomposes to "read XML file"," add a `<category2>` element inside a `<category1>`", and  "write XML back to file". Which bits have you implemented already and where did you get stuck?

Comment: @Botje, updated

Comment: Okay, what is wrong with this code? Does it crash? Does it give compiler errors? From what I read you're better   off allocating `newCategory2` on the heap with `new`.

Comment: @Botje: InsertEndChild will create a new node using TiXml memory model. This node will be built (copied) from the input node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TiXML does not accept spaces between XMLs tags as `</category2 >`, it must be `</category2>`. Your LoadFile will return false and the node will not be inserted.

This following code works as expected :

```
    const char * szTiXML = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?>"
        "<category1>"
        "<category2 name=\"1\">1.79639 0.430521</category2>"
        "<category2 name=\"2\">2.06832 0.652695</category2>"
        "<category2 name=\"3\">1.23123 0.111212</category2>"
        "</category1>";

    TiXmlDocument doc;
    doc.Parse( szTiXML );
    //if (doc.LoadFile()) 
    {
        TiXmlHandle docHandle(&doc);
        TiXmlElement* fileLog = docHandle.FirstChild("category1").ToElement();
        if (fileLog) {
            TiXmlElement newCategory2("category2");
            TiXmlText myText("Hello From SO");

            newCategory2.SetAttribute("name", "5");
            newCategory2.InsertEndChild(myText);

            fileLog->InsertEndChild(newCategory2);
        }

        doc.Print(stdout);
    }
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<category1>
    <category2 name="1">1.79639 0.430521</category2>
    <category2 name="2">2.06832 0.652695</category2>
    <category2 name="3">1.23123 0.111212</category2>
    <category2 name="5">Hello From SO</category2>
</category1>
```

Comment: How I can get next : <category2 name="5" >text</category2>

Comment: @bobtorus: I edited my answer. You can add text as you want in your application.